# Ler arquivo JS antes do PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Apenas uma dúvida, eu fiz uma tela de cadastro em HTML, e criei um arquivo JavaScript onde verifica a quantidade de senha e se as senhas são iguais. E fiz um arquivo recebe.php, onde irá mandar as informações do cadastro para o banco local (pois estou testando). Agora vem a minha dúvida, caso eu coloque senha diferentes, ele me mostra um alerta, falando que as senha são diferentes, porém quando clico no ok, ele salva as informações no banco, não era para fazer isto, era para voltar para a tela, para usuário colocar novamente a senha, o mesmo acontece quando a senha tem menos de 6 dígitos.

Arquivo JS

```
function Salvar(){

    senha1 = document.f1.senha1.value;
    senha2 = document.f1.senha2.value;

    if (senha1 == senha2){
            document.getElementById("senha1").style.borderColor="#bfc4c6";
            document.getElementById("senha2").style.borderColor="#bfc4c6";
        }

    else{
            document.getElementById("senha1").style.borderColor="#f00"; //caso for diferente irá mudar a cor do campo
            document.getElementById("senha2").style.borderColor="#f00";
            alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES");
             window.location="cadastro.html";
        }
}
```

Arquivo php:

```
<?php

    include_once 'conexao.php';

    $nome=$_POST['nome'];
    $cpf=$_POST['cpf'];
    $telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
     $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    //$senha1=$_POST['senha1'];
    $senha1 = md5($_POST['senha1']);

    $sql1 = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Email='$email' or usuario='$usuario'");

    if(

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql1) > 0){
        echo "Este usuario ja existe!";
        echo "<script>window.location='index.html';alert('Este usuario/email ja existe');</script>"; //irá redirecionar para página de login
    } else {
        $sql2 = $dbcon->query("INSERT INTO clientes (usuario,nome,cpf,telefone,email,senha1) VALUES('$usuario','$nome','$cpf','$telefone','$email','$senha1')");

    if($sql2){
            //echo  "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content=0;URL=index.html>";
            echo "<script>window.location='index.html';alert('$nome, cadastro realizado com sucesso');</script>"; //irá redirecionar para página de login
    }else{
            echo "registro_erro";
        }
    }
    if(!mpty($_POST['nome'])){
        echo "<script>window.location='cadastro.html';alert('Campos obrigatorios');</script>";

    }
?>
```

Codigo HTML

```
<div class="input-div" id="input-senha1"><b>Senha:</b>
     <input type="password" required id="senha1" name="senha1" placeholder="Insira senha " onkeyup="javascript:verifica()">
     <table id="mostra"></table>
</div>
<div class="input-div" id="input-senha2"><b>Confirmar senha:</b>
     <input type="password" required id="senha2" name="senha2" placeholder="Digite novamente a senha ">
</div>
<div class="content">
    <input type="submit" class="botao01"  onclick="Salvar();" value="Salvar" />
</div>
```

Não consegui colocar o código com as tags do html

Comment: Além da verificação pelo JavaScript você deve verificar também no PHP e impedir que o código que salva no banco seja executado. Mas seria melhor que o formulário nem fosse enviado caso as senhas não confiram. Mas o que não deu pra entender direito é o uso da função `Salvar()`. Como vc a está chamando e qual a função desse redirecionamento `window.location="cadastro.html";`?

Comment: Você pode executar a validação das senhas via blur nos campos, acredito que fique melhor no seu caso.

Comment: eu coloquei o código html, mas não consegui colocar com as tags.

Comment: No caso você teria que colocar dessa forma para redirecionar de volta para tela de login:
`window.location.pathname="cadastro.html"`, e além disso, impedir o envio do form no caso de senha incorreta.

Comment: Mas, como eu faria isto Matheus Spoo? pois tentei dessa maneira colocando no arquivo do javascript e depois no php, mas não deu certo não, ele volta para a tela, mas salva os dados. Mas era para impedi isto. Eu percebi que o arquivo php é lido antes do javascript

Comment: Antes de redirecionar você deve parar o comportamento padrão do clique, que no caso é um enviar o formulário. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Paulo, eu coloquei evt.preventDefault();, porém ele continua salvando quando a senha tem menos de 6 dígitos :(

Answer (score 0):

O [event.preventDevault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) funciona perfeitamente.

Recomendo que além de validar no front-end, também valide no back-end.

Apenas para fins didáticos, segue abaixo uma implementação bem próxima do seu exemplo. Veja que neste caso coloquei tudo em uma única página .php.

Testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

Espero que ajude.

```
<?php
/*
CREATE TABLE `teste`.`clientes`(  
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `senha` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `ativo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `clientes_email_unique` (`email`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `clientes_usuario_unique` (`usuario`),
  INDEX `clientes_ativo_email_index` (`email`, `ativo`),
  INDEX `clientes_ativo_usuario_index` (`usuario`, `ativo`)
);
*/
function conecta(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario-do-banco', 'senha', 'nome-do-banco');
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Não foi possível contectar ao banco de dados. Motivo:', $mysqli->connect_error));
    }
    return $mysqli;
}

function normalizaDados(array $post){
    $nome       = !empty($post['nome']) ? trim($post['nome']) : null;
    $email      = !empty($post['email']) ? trim($post['email']) : null;
    $usuario    = !empty($post['usuario']) ? trim($post['usuario']) : null;
    $cpf        = !empty($post['cpf']) ? trim($post['cpf']) : null;
    $telefone   = !empty($post['telefone']) ? trim($post['telefone']) : null;
    $senha      = !empty($post['senha']) ? trim($post['senha']) : null;
    $confirmar  = !empty($post['confirmar-senha']) ? trim($post['confirmar-senha']) : null;

    return [
        'nome'      => $nome,
        'email'     => $email,
        'usuario'   => $usuario,
        'cpf'       => $cpf,
        'telefone'  => $telefone,
        'senha'     => $senha,
        'confirmar' => $confirmar,
    ];
}

function validaCamposObrigatorios(array $dados){
    //todos os campos sao obrigatorios
    foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('O campo "%s" é obrigatório.', $key));
        }
    }
}

function validaSenha($senha, $confirmar){
    if (strlen($senha) < 6) {
        throw new Exception('A senha deve ter ao menos 6 caracteres.');
    }
    if ($senha !== $confirmar) {
        throw new Exception('As senhas não conferem.');
    }
}

function validaEmail($dbcon, $email){
    $stmt = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `clientes` WHERE `email` = ? LIMIT 1;');
    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception('Erro ao preparar a consulta de validação de e-mail.');
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->close();
        throw new Exception('Erro ao executar a consulta de validação de e-mail.');
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    if ($id) {
        throw new Exception('E-mail já utilizado.');
    }
}

function validaUsuario($dbcon, $email){
    $stmt = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `clientes` WHERE `usuario` = ? LIMIT 1;');
    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception('Erro ao preparar a consulta de validação de usuário.');
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->close();
        throw new Exception('Erro ao executar a consulta de validação de usuário.');
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    if ($id) {
        throw new Exception('Usuário já utilizado.');
    }
}

function validaDados($dbcon, array $dados){
    validaCamposObrigatorios($dados);
    validaSenha($dados['senha'], $dados['confirmar']);
    validaEmail($dbcon, $dados['email']);
    validaUsuario($dbcon, $dados['usuario']);
}

function insereDados($dbcon, array $dados){
    $stmt = $dbcon->prepare('INSERT INTO `clientes`(`nome`, `email`, `usuario`, `cpf`, `telefone`, `senha`, `ativo`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1);');
    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception('Erro ao preparar a consulta de criação do cliente.');
    }
    $stmt->bind_param(
        'ssssss', 
        $dados['nome'], 
        $dados['email'], 
        $dados['usuario'], 
        $dados['cpf'], 
        $dados['telefone'], 
        md5($dados['senha']) 
    );
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $error = $stmt->error;
        $stmt->close();
        throw new Exception('Erro ao executar a consulta de criação de cliente: ' . $error);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $dbcon->insert_id;
}

$mensagem = '';

$dados = normalizaDados($_POST);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    try{
        $dbcon = conecta();

        validaDados($dbcon, $dados);

        insereDados($dbcon, $dados);

        //para redirecionar para o login.php
        //tirar o comentário das linhas abaixo.
        //header('Location: /login.php');
        //exit;

        $mensagem = 'Usuário inserido com sucesso.';

        $dados = normalizaDados([]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $mensagem = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cadastro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" id="formulario" onsubmit="validaFormulario(event)">
            <div id="mensagem"><?php echo $mensagem; ?></div>

            <div>
                <label for="nome">Nome: *</label>
                <input type="text" required minlength="6" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" value="<?php echo $dados['nome']; ?>">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email">E-mail: *</label>
                <input type="email" required id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php echo $dados['email']; ?>">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="usuario">Usuário: *</label>
                <input type="text" required minlength="4" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" value="<?php echo $dados['usuario']; ?>">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="senha">Senha: *</label>
                <input type="password" required minlength="6" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Insira senha" onkeyup="comparaSenhas()">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="confirmar-senha">Confirmar senha: *</label>
                <input type="password" required minlength="6" id="confirmar-senha" name="confirmar-senha" placeholder="Confirme a senha " onkeyup="comparaSenhas()">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="cpf">CPF: *</label>
                <input type="text" required id="cpf" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" value="<?php echo $dados['cpf']; ?>">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="telefone">Telefone: *</label>
                <input type="text" required id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" value="<?php echo $dados['telefone']; ?>">
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
            </div>
        </form>

        <script>
            var $senha = document.getElementById('senha');
            var $confirmarSenha = document.getElementById('confirmar-senha');
            var $mensagem = document.getElementById('mensagem');

            function comparaSenhas(){
                if ($senha.value && $confirmarSenha.value && $senha.value == $confirmarSenha.value) {
                    $mensagem.innerText = '';
                    return true;
                } 
                if ($senha.value && $confirmarSenha.value) {
                    $mensagem.innerText = 'As senhas não conferem.';
                }
                return false;
            }

            function validaFormulario(event) {
                console.log('validando o formulário...');
                if (!comparaSenhas()) {
                    console.log('formulário inválido! submit impedido.');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                console.log('formulário valido!');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```